# Using different profiles for Maven Modules

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I'm trying to work in a multimodule maven project. The whole company have a pom project where we have defined two maven profiles: application - it's used when we are building an application (zip have to be created, etc), module - when we are building a simple common module. Let's call this pom project as build.module

Now there is a maven multimodule project which is also using the build.module. This project contains two modules, one is the application (**myapp**) which should be built with "**application**" profile, and another one which is a common module (**mycommon**) which should be built with "**module**" profile.

If I run the mvn clean install to the multimodule there I can just specify the profiles used, but I don't want to be built both modules with the same profile, I would like to have some kind of control over them.

While I have multiple modules in the multimodule project there can be also defined additional profiles to control which modules should be built.

My question is how I could manage to build my multimodule project in a way that the **myapp** is built with "**application**" profile while the **mycommon** is built with "**module**" profile?

--> build module

-----> multimoduleproject

---------> mycommon

---------> myapp

Thank you so much, if you know how to do that you could help me a lot :)

Have a nice day.

Comment: We solved the problem by activating/deactivating the profiles through marker files that are present/absent in the modules. This requires, though, that you change the parent POM, which you probably don't want to do.

Comment: I may do it. Could you tell a bit more about this solution ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We defined something like

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>findbugs</id>
    <activation>
      <file>
        <exists>${basedir}/.mvn/active-profiles/findbugs</exists>
      </file>
    </activation>
    ...
```

This allows you to activate findbugs by adding a file named `findbugs` to the respective directory. Your problem should be solvable along the same lines.

A side remark: I decided to replace most of the profiles by properties (that skip/enable plugins) in the future because we want to gather all information inside the POM. Nevertheless, the solution with the profiles is working well for about 2 years now.